# optional locals within terragrunt configs?

Tags: terraform, terragrunt, hcl

If we take the following structure as an example, is there a way to make locals within the .hcl files optional?

```
.
├── terragrunt.hcl
└── global_vars.hcl/
    └── lz_vars.hcl/
        └── workload_vars.hcl/
            └── terragrunt.hcl
```

I've tried the following which fails as it's expecting the tags locals to be available in all configs, when including tags in all configs, we have success when I omit 1 or more tags attributes, we get the error below.

```
  global_vars   = (read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("global.hcl"))).locals
  env_vars      = (read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("env.hcl"))).locals
  workload_vars = (read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("workload.hcl"))).locals

  tags = merge(
    try(local.global_vars..tags, {}),
    try(local.lz_vars.tags, {}),
    try(local.workload_vars.tags, {})
  )
```

I could just add a blank tags locals attribute but, this feels untidy.

**Error message**

```
Unsupported attribute; This object does not have an attribute named "tags".
```

Expected = Tags merge and ommitted tags are defined as blank attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the scenario based on your inputs and in my case it just worked, out of the box. This is the project I came up with, based on your scenario:

```
.
└── global
    ├── global.hcl
    └── lz
        ├── lz.hcl
        └── workload
            └── terragrunt.hcl
```

`global/global.hcl`

```
locals {
  #tags = {
  #  global-tag = "foobar"
  #}
  project-name = "tom & jerry"
}
```

`global/lz/lz.hcl`

```
locals {
  tags = {
    lz-tag = "blabla"
  }
}
```

`global/lz/workload/terragrunt.hcl`

```
terraform {
  source = "git::https://github.com/bernardhalas/terraform-trainings.git//2-modules/vm-module"
}

locals {
  workload-tags = {
    workload-name = "merge-sort"
  }
  global_vars   = (read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("global.hcl"))).locals
  lz_vars      = (read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("lz.hcl"))).locals

  tags = merge(
    try(local.global_vars.tags, {}),
    try(local.lz_vars.tags, {}),
    try(local.workload-tags, {})
  )
}
```

Comment: Just confirming the code now works, not sure why I received an error previously.